# Change the order of column using css

Tags: html, css

I have 5 items and I want to change the order of these div-items like I have items (1,2,3,4,5) and I want to change the order like(3,5,1,2,4)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="div-container">
  <div class="div-item">1</div>
  <div class="div-item">2</div>
  <div class="div-item">3</div>
  <div class="div-item">4</div>
  <div class="div-item">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do bear in mind that this change of order isn't necessarily reflected by assistive technologies; so if the changed order is meaningful then consider using JavaScript to change the order in the DOM to assist non-visual users, with screen-readers (as an example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex properties like

```
.div-container {
  display: flex;
}

.div-item:nth-of-type(1) { order: 3; }
.div-item:nth-of-type(2) { order: 4; }
.div-item:nth-of-type(3) { order: 1; }
.div-item:nth-of-type(4) { order: 5; }
.div-item:nth-of-type(5) { order: 2; }
```